# add new elements to class

Tags: flutter, dart

I've written a class like this,

```
      class LessonCategory{final String name;
       LessonCategory(this.name);

     @override
     String toString() {
     return 'LessonCategory{name: $name}';
        }
       }  

    class Lessons {
      final String lessonsName;
      int discontinuity;
      final LessonCategory lesscategory;
      Lessons(this.lessonsName, this.discontinuity, 
      this.lesscategory,
        );

   @override
   String toString() {
   return 'Lessons{lessonsName: $lessonsName, discontinuity: 
   $discontinuity, lesscategory: $lesscategory}';
    }
   }


    class Data {
      static List<LessonCategory> categories = [
      LessonCategory("a1"),
       ];
    static List<Lessons> lessons = [
     Lessons(
        'Lesson A1',
         0,
         getCategoryFromName("a1"),
         ),
       ];

    static LessonCategory getCategoryFromName(name) {
    return categories.firstWhere(
      (c) => c.name.toLowerCase() == name.toString().toLowerCase());
     }
     }
```

But I can't figure out how to add a new element.I already tried add,push,insert (or i missed something).
Can someone please show me the right way?

i want something like

```
    Data.lessons.add({
       lessonsName: 'Lesson Z1',
       discontinuity: 0
       lessCategory: 'a1'
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove static syntax. if it is defined as static, it will be immutable

```dart
class Data {
  static List<LessonCategory> categories = [
    LessonCategory("a1"),
  ];
  List<Lessons> lessons = [ // Remove Static syntax
    Lessons(
      'Lesson A1',
      0,
      getCategoryFromName("a1"),
    ),
  ];

  static LessonCategory getCategoryFromName(name) {
    return categories.firstWhere(
        (c) => c.name.toLowerCase() == name.toString().toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

but also we can correct another syntaxes

```dart
Data newData = Data();
  newData.lessons.add(Lessons(
    'Lesson Z1', // remove named parameters, and use positional params
    0,
    LessonCategory('a1'),
  ));
  print("New Length : ${newData.lessons.length}");
```

### Fully working code

```dart
class LessonCategory {
  final String name;
  LessonCategory(this.name);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'LessonCategory{name: $name}';
  }
}

class Lessons {
  final String lessonsName;
  int discontinuity;
  final LessonCategory lesscategory;
  Lessons(
    this.lessonsName,
    this.discontinuity,
    this.lesscategory,
  );

  @override
  String toString() {
    return """Lessons{lessonsName: $lessonsName, discontinuity: $discontinuity, lesscategory: $lesscategory}""";
  }
}

class Data {
  static List<LessonCategory> categories = [
    LessonCategory("a1"),
  ];
  List<Lessons> lessons = [ // Remove Static syntax
    Lessons(
      'Lesson A1',
      0,
      getCategoryFromName("a1"),
    ),
  ];

  static LessonCategory getCategoryFromName(name) {
    return categories.firstWhere(
        (c) => c.name.toLowerCase() == name.toString().toLowerCase());
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "{${lessons.map((fruit) => print(fruit))}}";
  }
}

main(List<String> args) {
  Data newData = Data(); // Create instance first


  newData.lessons.add(Lessons(
    'Lesson Z1', // remove named parameters, and use positional params
    0,
    LessonCategory('a1'),
  ));
  print("New Length : ${newData.lessons.length}");

  newData.lessons.add(Lessons(
    'Lesson Z1',
    0,
    LessonCategory('a1'),
  ));
  print("New Length : ${newData.lessons.length}");

  print("${newData.lessons}");
}
```

which we able to play arount in [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/cbca6da21ab5016a8b1ecc6612eb0dca)

### Result

[image]

Comment: Only static members can be accessed in initializer  says for 'getCategoryFromName' :/

Comment: just remove static at Lessons variable

Answer (score 0):

remove the static syntax and the problem will be solved

Comment: Only static members can be accessed in initializer  says for 'getCategoryFromName' :/